# Which Stack Exchange site for this type of question?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-exchange, site-recommendation

> Which is the most popular Chiclet keyboard in the world same as laptop?

> What proxy to use for online  flash games?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no Stack Exchange site for that sort of question.

Stack Exchange runs question and answer sites, not polls or popularity contests, especially not for "questions" whose answers are short-lived and spam magnets (both your examples fit both these criteria).

You'll need to look outside this network to post such polls.

Comment: do you know any other site please help?